# Array of Expressions to an Array Definition

Tags: metaprogramming, julia

I am writing a macro that makes it easier to write function definitions in a specific case, and the output is an expression for an array. I have gotten pretty far, and currently I can parse input into an expression of arrays, like

```
x = Expr[:(ones(length(u[:,1])) - 0.5 * u[:,1]),:(ones(length(u[:,2])) - u[:,2])]
```

But I need to take this and have it define the array where the columns are those expressions, like

```
[(ones(length(u[:,1])) - 0.5 * u[:,1]) (ones(length(u[:,2])) - u[:,2])]
```

And be able to do that for an arbitrary length expression array `x`. Is there a good way to construct this output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression head for the form `[a b]` is `hcat`. So e.g. `Expr(:hcat, x...)` should work.

Comment: Beautiful. We arrived at something close to this in the Gitter chat. Yours is slightly nicer since instead of looping it just splats. Thanks!